# How should I install Far Manager into Cmder?

Tags: conemu, far-manager, cmder

I have just unzipped the cmder package. Cmder wraps ConEmu nicely. But how do I install Far Manager properly?

I can think of `cmder\`, `cmder\vendor\` and `cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\` as possible locations, but I have actually no clue how to approach this since ConEmu is wrapped inside Cmder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, doesn't matter where you've installed Far Manager. The only significant condition - Far must load ConEmu plugin.

1. Update ConEmu to the latest build.
2. Install Far using msi package, goto ConEmu settings and press "Add default tasks" on the tasks page. Far task will be created for you.
3. Or, you may create task manually - just don't forget about /p switch - pass both ConEmu/plugins and Far/plugins folder.

Also. You can unpack Far distro into "conemu-maximus5" folder (far.exe will be in the same folder as ConEmu.exe). In that case you may just run "far.exe" from new console dialog.

Comment: I now have unpacked Far Manager into `cmder\vendor\ ` and updated init.bat to `@if exist "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\farmanager" ( set PATH=%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\farmanager;%PATH%")`

[taken from here](https://github.com/narnaud/cmderplus/blob/master/vendor/init.bat). This looks like your last recommendation right?

Comment: I'd said "don't forget about /p switch". Have you created a Task?

Comment: <del>Yes, I have now one task with a /p switch. I think the ConEmu plugins aren't loaded, doesn't show an entry for Lines, or Thumbs..
`%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\farmanager\far.exe /p"%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\plugins;"%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\farmanager\Plugins\"`</del>

Sorry, it seems ConEmu plugins are loaded right now, since it is possible to view thumbnails now.

Comment: It seems ConEmu plugins are loaded correctly, since it is possible to view thumbnails now! Sorry, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want Far Manager to store its settings in `%CMDER_ROOT%\config` you'll want Far.exe.ini to reflect that as well.

```
UseSystemProfiles=0
;When 0, configuration will be stored in UserProfileDir, UserLocalProfileDir
UserProfileDir=%CMDER_ROOT%\config\FAR\Profile 
;UserLocalProfileDir=%CMDER_ROOT%\FAR\config\Profile
;By default UserLocalProfileDir == UserProfileDir
```

It used to be that if Far.exe were in the same place as ConEmu.exe that ConEmu would launch with a Far Manager tab, not so much anymore so installing it to `cmder\vendor\` would be the 'suggested' install location.

Comment: correction: ```UserProfileDir=%CMDER_ROOT%\config\FAR\Profile
;UserLocalProfileDir=%CMDER_ROOT%\FAR\config\Profile```

Comment: Please don't use comments for corrections. Edit your answer instead.